# Implementing __cpuid example from MSDN gives insanely large numbers

Tags: c++, breakpoints, msdn, cpuid

I'm quickly implementing this code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh(v=vs.80).aspx into my program, since I needed to get some CPU info, however when i get to this part of the code:

```
__cpuid(CPUInfo, 0x80000000);
    nExIds = CPUInfo[0];
```

the next for loop begins to roll forever, so I placed a break point and the hit count kept growing, turned out that *nExIDs* gets set to *2147483656*, which would make the execution of the rest of the code hours if not weeks(so it's obviously an error).It doesn't say the feature is deprecated or anything, so it shouldn't be giving me trouble, right?If it's relevant to the *__cpuid* function, I'm running it on **Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit** on a **VAIO** laptop.The CPU I'm querying is an **Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU M 460 @ 2.53GHz** with **2** cores(**4 logical**).Maybe I need to pass it a different value other than *0x80000000*?But how do I determine how much?

Comment: If you post the code you are using we may be able to help.

Comment: Did any of the other InfoTypes documented at that page work?  What did they return?

Comment: @Rich: It's at the page he linked.  There is, of course, no guarantee that it is bug-free.

Comment: Thanks @RobertHarvey had to scroll a bit to find

Comment: Yes the others worked, I'm using the exact source of the page, if I get it to work from there, then I'll tweak it up, etc. but even the one from msdn seems to not be working(at least for me).

Comment: hmm at that line the value of CPUInfo[0] is a 1, yet nExIds gets set to a huge number(and the number is different each time it's executed)I'm actualy setting nExIds to 0 the line before and checking the value of CPUInfo[0] and it still becomes an invalid number.

Comment: Did you read this part of the page you linked?  "If this is supported, InfoType values from 0x8000000 might be used to return information. To determine the maximum meaningful value allowed, set InfoType to 0x8000000."

Comment: nFeatureInfo = CPUInfo[3] also sets it to an invalid value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, the example in *MSDN* has a bug - if the feature is not supported it sets it to a negative value, but *nExIds* is an **unsigned int**, so when you set it to the negative invalid value, it automatically gets set to *2147483656*.So I must use **int** instead of **unsigned int**.